# Make different size images to be responsive using next/image

Tags: next.js, nextjs-image

I'm using next.js version 12 in my project. I have blocks that contain images with different sizes. I want to use next/image, but I'm new to it and couldn't figure out how to make different size images to be responsive.

If I use layout="responsive", I need to fix the sizes, but I have different sizes:

```
<Image src={`/images/${image}`} key={item} width={500} height={300} layout={'responsive'} />
```

When I use layout="fill", I need to give sizes to parent div and again that is not what I want.
Is there a way to achieve what I want without writing a function that will check each image size and give it to image component?

Answer (score 1):

There is a kind of hack to do it.
First you wrap image with container.

```
<div className={'image-container'}>
  <Image src={path} layout="fill" className={'image'} />
</div>
```

Then you add CSS:

```
 .image-container {

  width: 100%;

  > div {
    position: unset !important;
  }

  .image {
    object-fit: contain;
    width: 100% !important;
    position: relative !important;
    height: unset !important;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy to discover, but the correct recipe would be something like this:

```
 <Image
    sizes="(min-width: 768px) 80px, 60px"
    layout="responsive"
    alt="Logo IE"
    width={230}
    height={208}
    src="/src/image.jpg"
  />
```

I use width and height with the max size (helping next to know the aspect ratio) and the sizes attirbute to set size to use in the diferent resolutions as documented here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images#resolution_switching_different_sizes